# Lipschitz dependence on ODE parameters in discrete setting

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Consider the ordinary differential equation
$$ x'(t) = e^{-x(t)} - p$$
with (time-independent) non-negative parameter $p$. Its solution after time $t$ is given by
$$ \Phi^t_px_0 = \log\left( e^{x_0 - pt} + \frac{1 - e^{-pt}}p \right)$$
A tedious but straight-forward computation reveals that this flow satisfies the Lipschitz condition
$$ |\Phi^t_px_0 - \Phi^t_qx_0| \le t |p-q|\text.$$

I have, furthermore, checked this property for

1. any discrete flow from the family
   $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \Delta t [\lambda f(x_n) + (1-\lambda) f(x_{n+1})]$$
2. any discrete flow from the family
   $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \Delta t f(\lambda x_n + (1-\lambda) x_{n+1})$$

with $\lambda \in [0,1]$. In particular, these families include

1. the forward Euler method,
2. the backward Euler method,
3. the trapezoidal rule, and
4. the implicit midpoint rule

**My question now is**: Is this just a coincidence or can we say that a certain class of discrete flows always inherits this property, regardless of the form of the continuous flow?

I find this inheritance somewhat surprising: A priori, the above discrete flows  should only approximate the continuous flow well locally, while the property in question is global.